# How can we assign permissions to setup SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, sql-server-administration, sql-server-authentication

In SQL Server 2012, how can we give a permission to someone to have full control to SSRS and a permission to a specific Db so they can configure and run the SSRS reports and have a full control to backup/restore their Databases but do not have control to other databases on the same SQL Server machine?

Comment: Will the User use SQL login or NTLM  and did you want them to alter the data, `table, procedure, views`..etc ?

Comment: @Searching SQL Login with full control on his/her database and be able to configure and run SSRS reports for his/her database. But no access to the databases of other users.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you create a sql user login called `sqllogin`, Leave this user's `Server roles` as `public`.

[image: login properties]

Under `Login Properties` section for this user in `User Mapping` select the one database you want them against (in the list on rightside) and choose the following roles

```
db_backupoperator
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_ddladmin
```

[image: permission example]

Note: not all options are ticked in image.

This allows user login only to `tempdb` (for this example) and not the others. They might be able to see other databases but cannot access them in anyway.

More info on roles [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx)

As far as SSRS is concerned, create a `datasource` mapped to this database with this `sqllogin`.This is not the same as permission to SSRS but only to the database they get access to.

[image: sample]

SSRS permissions are different, I'm pretty sure the sql login cannot be used. This might be of help [Authentication SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx).

But I hope this gets you started.